# Adding options to products (with additional pricing)

Tags: custom-options

Please excuse if this is a very fundamental question. A client has asked for some help with an existing Magento build and I have never touched it before.

He has a product selling for £299 and wants to be able to sell it at base price or sell it with installation for an extra £99. Is this possible? I have toyed around with attributes but all I managed to do was lose the buy now button on the product page and no mention of the option.

Searching brings up confusing results mostly dominated by paid add ons.

Can someone point me in the right direction for this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use Custom Options Luke**

When editing a product in the backend you will see a tab called 'Custom Options'.
From there you can add on a product different types of inputs for a customer to fill in.

In your case you need a custom option with type `checkbox`.
Select `checkbox`, fill in a title, make it not required.
Then click on `Add new row`, fill in the title `Installation`, the price `99.00` and save.

Comment: we can discount price by custom option?

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR This is an entirely separate question and doesn't belong attached to the current question/answer - you should submit it as its own question.

Comment: @Marius Looks like that will do the trick. The order button is missing from the page now, though so I'm assuming this is a template issue (the current order button is styled differently from "standard") so I'll have to dig around for the appropriate template code. Thanks for your help.